# Is there a way to create a brand new Ionic/Angular project which uses ESLint instead of TSLint?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, eslint, tslint

I don't want to convert to Eslint every time I create a new Ionic/Angular project is there a way to configure Eslint as default?

Answer (score 1):

As of now, angular/ionic CLI does not have an option to select Eslint as an default linter. I was also wondering the same so created a small script to help me configure Eslint on new project creation:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $1 = "" ]]
then
    echo "Please provide project name"
    exit 1
fi
ionic start $1
cd $PWD/$1
ng add @angular-eslint/schematics
# For angular project update following with this -> ng g @angular-eslint/schematics:convert-tslint-to-eslint $1
ng g @angular-eslint/schematics:convert-tslint-to-eslint app
```

Simply execute this script with the project name.